# RAII using custom deleter of unique_ptr

Tags: c++, c++11, raii

I want to do automatic cleanup using std::unique_ptr but to initialize the unique_ptr I need an address to point to. How can I avoid the noUse variable?

```cpp
bool noUse;
auto deleter = [](bool *){ DESTROY_SOMETHING }; 
std::unique_ptr<bool, decltype(deleter)> upp(&noUse, deleter); // I want to avoid the usage of this extra noUse variable
START_SOMETHING

//COMPLEX IF ELSE RETURN LOGIC
```

**UPDATE: **
I finally resorted to this code. Thanks everyone for quick responses.

```cpp
auto deleter = [](void *){ DESTROY_SOMETHING };
std::unique_ptr<void, decltype(deleter)> upp(nullptr, deleter);

if(enabled)
{
   //START_SOMETHING
   upp.reset(reinterpret_cast<void *>&upp);
}

//COMPLEX IF ELSE RETURN LOGIC
```

Comment: what is `SOMETHING`? How does `deleter` delete something?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Simple way to execute code at the end of function scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50182244/simple-way-to-execute-code-at-the-end-of-function-scope)

Comment: Don't abuse `std::unique_ptr`.

Comment: Once I wrote my own `ScopeGuard` for some project, and then decided it's just not worth the effort. Now I just use `std::shared_ptr<void> scopeGuard` for this kind of scenarios. I think the name of the variable makes the intent clear. [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/bEW5Kavz6)

Comment: Note that you are much better off writing a something-wrapping-smart-pointer and reusing it than writing per-scope cleanup code.  Even if that means there are multiple destructors that have to run in a scope.  Sorry, ESPECIALLY if that means there are multiple destructors that have to run in a scope.  Because the compiler will keep track of which cleanup code to run if an exception occurs partway through the initialization.

Comment: Can you explain why you need to avoid an extra variable?

Comment: If you make the deleter take `void*` (and use `unique_ptr<void, decltype(deleter)>`), then you can pass `&deleter` itself as the pointer value, or even `&upp`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as the custom deleter doesn't require `noUse` to have any specific value, you can use some arbitrary integer literal (other than zero, that would make it a null pointer):

```cpp
auto deleter = [](bool *){ DESTROY_SOMETHING };

// slightly longer but more robust:          reinterpret_cast<bool*>(&upp)
std::unique_ptr<bool, decltype(deleter)> upp(reinterpret_cast<bool*>(1), deleter);
// ...
```

This is a bit of a hack, and there are better solutions, such as [`std::experimental::scope_exit`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/scope_exit). It also doesn't make much sense that this is using a `bool*`, why not just a `void*` if we don't care about the type?

You can also build your own solution, see:

- [Simple way to execute code at the end of function scope](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50182244/5740428)
- [Call a function before function exits](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33031334/5740428)

@Joe has written [a solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50182372/5740428) very similar to `std::experimental::scope_exit` which does this.

---

*Note 1: conversion of `1` to `bool*` has implementation-defined effect ([[expr.reinterpret_cast]](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.reinterpret.cast#5)), using this pointer is implementation-defined ([[basic.stc.general]](https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.stc#general-4)), and comparison of the pointer to `nullptr` is implementation-defined, though never UB ([[expr.eq]](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.eq#3)).*

*Note 2: Developers commonly create a local `static` variable and take its address when they need a `std::unique_ptr` as a "scope exit object". This is the most robust option.*